# Non Latin characters in friendly url for searching purposes

Tags: php, url, non-latin

**Context**: I want to allow non latin characters in my url.
**Why**: Search term would be part of a url. *Example*: example.tld/**search-term**
**Facts**: Only modern browsers would show decoded characters, cause they MUST use [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for internal purposes. But some sites, like [wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0), use NON-Latin characters in their URLs.

**Question**:

What should I do? Which problem(s) could I have by allowing search-terms to be passed that way? Should I do something special to  retrieve this term form my php file? Any url encoding function?

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: The search terms that you send to your search func/class/procedure should be parsed in exactly the same way the data that is to be searched on is parsed (before being saved), then how they show in the URL is not an issue.

Comment: @popnoodles Thanks. So, internally, if I get the search term directly from the url, it will ALWAYS BE PERCENT-ENCODED, even if the browser shows it decoded to the user, right? - Just to be sure :D

Comment: No, unless I'm mistaken PHP urldecodes from $_GET regardless, but in any case `urldecode()` is your friend

Comment: So, you are not mistaken. PHP manual says $_GET is already decoded, and decoding them again is bad. Thanks for your great help.